# Call notifications for agent web interface on GoAutodial

Tags: asterisk

The problem is simple, agents login to the web interface using firefox, they get involved with other tasks that require them to use other windows therefore Firefox is hidden so they do not get a notification or alarm on the web page. is there a desktop client or a notifications method to show the agent that there is an incoming call

Answer (score 0):

Firefox support screen popups.

http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-useful-notifications-with-html5-apis/163

There is also addon for older firefox https://code.google.com/p/ff-html5notifications/

Also you can create desktop application which will sit in background and popup when needed(not so costly)

Comment: Do you know any ready to use application, or I have to build it myself

Comment: already build application is FOP2(asternic.org). but it is nto free. sorry,i am not aware of any free app like that.